# Gateway Timeout Django

Tags: python, django, iis

Имеется сайт на Django запущенный на виртуальной машине. Когда запускаю сайт локально на виртуальной машине через runserver, то все работает как нужно. Но если запускаю с условием runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 (чтобы подключаться с другой машины в локальной корпоративной сети), то при запуске на сайте тяжелых запросов (со сроком выполнения больше минуты с обращением к базе Postgres), получаю ошибку Gateway Timeout. Но сам запрос не прерывается и продолжает свое выполнение. Не понимаю причину. Пытался и корректировать SETTINGS, добавляя TIMEOUT, и запускал из под IIS с указанием длительного TIMEOUT - результат один и тот же.
[[image: Gateway_timeout1]